# Different behavior for bool to string conversion with different gcc versions

Tags: c++, string, gcc, gcc-warning

I know I shouldn't do it but still I want to know how it works.

I am trying to compile a buggy code, where the return type of function is `std::string` and I am actually returning a boolean value:

```
// test.cpp
std::string donothing(int i)
{
  return false;
}
```

I know this shouldn't work and the error should be caught be the compiler but there is an interesting observation:

1. With gcc 4.8.5, I just get away with warning and compilation works.
2. With gcc 7.3.1, compilation fails.

Here are the compiler outputs:

```
// gcc 4.8.5
test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual std::string donothing(int)’:
test.cpp:9:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type for argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ [-Wconversion-null]
      return false;

// gcc 7.3.1
test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual std::__cxx11::donothing(int)’:
test.cpp:9:9: error: could not convert ‘false’ from ‘bool’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
      return false;
             ^~~~~
```

Comment: false = 0 = technically convertible to a pointer.

Comment: This duplicate does not take into account 1) The extra conversion to `std::string`, which changes the conversion sequence, 2) The difference in behavior between 4.8.5 and 7.3.1.

Comment: The code compiles with latest gcc with `-std=c++03` so this looks more related to a change in the standard between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: To me it looks like the difference is not the compiler version but the C++ standard version (the default changed between these GCC versions).

Comment: @Holt what a concidence. Nice to see you here (again).

Comment: @Holt You are right, but the root cause is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## GCC 7.3.1

By default, GCC 7.3.1 uses `-std=gnu++14`.  (I cannot find the GCC 7.3.1 manual, but FWIW, both the [GCC 7.4 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.4.0/gcc/Standards.html#C_002b_002b-Language) and the [GCC 6.5 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.5.0/gcc/Standards.html#C_002b_002b-Language) say so.)

Let's take a look at the synopsis of the class `basic_string` in C++14 ([[basic.string]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.string#string.cons)).  The only converting (non-explicit) constructor that receive one parameter is: <sup>1</sup>

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Therefore, the question is essentially: `false` cannot be implicitly converted to `const char*`. Per [[conv.ptr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/conv.ptr#1):

> A *null pointer constant* is **an integer literal ([lex.icon]) with
>   value zero** or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer
>   constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null
>   pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other
>   value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is
>   called a *null pointer conversion*. Two null pointer values of the
>   same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer
>   constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and
>   not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification
>   conversion ([conv.qual]). A null pointer constant of integral type can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [ *Note:* The
>   resulting prvalue is not a null pointer value. — *end note* ]

`false` is a boolean literal ([[lex.bool]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/lex.bool)) rather an integer literal.  Therefore, `false` cannot be implicitly converted to `const char*`.

<sup><sup>1</sup> In fact, there is one `initializer_list` constructor that meets the criteria, but it is omitted because it is apparently irrelevant.</sup>

## GCC 4.8.5

Per [GCC 4.8.5 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Standards.html#Standards):

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is
>   `-std=gnu++98`.

Again, let's take a look at the synopsis of the class `basic_string` in C++98 ([[lib.basic.string]](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/isocppstd/lib-strings.html#lib.basic.string)).   The only converting (non-explicit) constructor that receive one parameter is:

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Therefore, the question is essentially: `false` can be implicitly converted to `const char*`. Per [[conv.ptr]/1](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/isocppstd/conv.html#conv.ptr):

> A *null pointer constant* is **an integral constant expression
>   ([expr.const](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/isocppstd/expr.html#expr.const))
>   rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero**. A null pointer
>   constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null
>   pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other
>   value of pointer to object or pointer to function type. Two null
>   pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. The conversion of
>   a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single
>   conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a
>   qualification conversion
>   ([conv.qual](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/isocppstd/conv.html#conv.qual)).

`false` is an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type (`bool` is an integer type) that evaluates to zero. Therefore, `false` can be implicitly converted to `const char*`.

Comment: Well, it's quite confusing that `bool` is an integer type but `false` is not an integer literal...